# Difference Between "Text" and "String" datatype in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite database with my Android application.  I have noticed I accidentally defined a table using a "String" datatype instead of "Text" datatype.  Here is the code with string:

```
private final String LISTDATES_CREATE = "create table if not exists ListDates (_id integer primary key autoincrement, ListName string not null, UpdateDate string not null);";
```

This works. It has never thrown an error and I can store and retrieve data.  However I can't find any reference to a "String" datatype in SQLite in the documentation or on the internet.  Typically, all string type data is defined with "text" like so:

```
private final String LISTDATES_CREATE = "create table if not exists ListDates (_id integer primary key autoincrement, ListName text not null, UpdateDate text not null);";
```

So my question is, what is the difference between a field defined with a "string" datatype versus a "text" datatype?  Is there a difference?  If so, what are the consequences, if any, of using one or the other?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The subtle thing to note here is that SQLite does not enforce the data type of values you put into columns. That means that you can put text into a numeric field, and so on.

To understand the difference between your two SQL statements, check out section [2.1 Determination Of Column Affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), which maps the column types you provide to the storage classes SQLite uses.

In this case, the type `string` gets mapped to storage class `NUMERIC` via rule 5. Declaring the field as `text` in code would tell the DBMS to use the `TEXT` storage class.  Again, since SQLite does not enforce the types of columns, your code will probably run fine when storing Strings as a `NUMERIC` column, as you note.

As an alternative example, you could define a column with type `INTERESTING STUFF`, and that would be mapped to the `INTEGER` storage class, via rule 1.

Overall, it's probably a good idea to just use `text` for your table definition.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Once I found the mistake, I made the change but I unfortunately have code in production with this mistake.  Since it doesn't appear to be a major problem, I am just going to let them age off naturally.   This is really great information.  Thank you!

Answer (score 48):

This is an old question, but I want to highlight a specific difference between a STRING and TEXT column types. If a string looks like a numeric value, STRING will convert it into a numeric value, while TEXT will not perform any conversion.

e.g.

```
create table t1(myint INTEGER, mystring STRING, mytext TEXT);
insert into t1 values ('0110', '0220', '0330');
insert into t1 values ('-0110', '-0220', '-0330');
insert into t1 values ('+0110', '+0220', '+0330');
insert into t1 values ('x0110', 'x0220', 'x0330');
insert into t1 values ('011.0', '022.0', '033.0');
select * from t1
```

will output rows with values:

```
 myint mystring mytext
   110      220   0330
  -110     -220  -0330
   110      220  +0330
 x0110    x0220  x0330
    11       22  033.0
```

This means leading zeros, zeros trailing decimal points, and plus symbol on the "numeric" values will be stripped. This will cause problems if you intend on doing a string match using the values read out of the table.