# flask sqlalchemy database db.Text vs db.String

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Can any one tell me a meaningful specific example wher the use of db.Text surpasses db.String(limit)
like so

```
name=db.Column(db.Text)
```

or

```
name = db.Column(db.String(80))
```

. I want an internationally operational application please help because nothing I have seen so far is making it clear even the flask official website itself can I write Chines e in db.Text or what?

Comment: I suspect that it will also depend on your underlying RBDMS. Which are you using?

Comment: sqlite I just need to know if it makes a difference at allyou know?

Comment: For SQLite it shouldn't make any difference because it doesn't strictly enforce any types

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference Between "Text" and "String" datatype in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938401/difference-between-text-and-string-datatype-in-sqlite)

Comment: Thanks roganjosh you are an angel , you helped me very much

Comment: @roganjosh or OP you should post a new answer with the website link and mark it as an answer. That helps SO and other users to quickly identify it.

Comment: @Anders_K actually, I suspect that my close-vote just aged away. Thanks for bring it back up

Comment: @Anders_K Yes, thanks for bringing this to Josh's attention. But on SO we *don't* post duplicate links as answers. The system has a better procedure for handling duplicates. On a related note, an answer that just consists of a link to material *not* on SO  is considered to be a non-answer, as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/334566).