# What is meant by saying that String is a numeric type in android SQlite?

Tags: android, string, sqlite

I specified columns datatype as String while creating database in my android project.I encountered the below lines as suggestions.What does that mean?

Using column type STRING; did you mean to use TEXT? (STRING is a numeric type and its value can be adjusted; for example, strings that look like integers can drop leading zeroes.

Comment: [Difference Between "Text" and "String" datatype in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938401/difference-between-text-and-string-datatype-in-sqlite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the *data typ*e `String` because there is no such *data type* in SQLite.

Actually SQLite does not use *data types* but 5 **storage classes** for each value stored (not for each column):

> NULL, INTEGER, REAL, TEXT and BLOB

Also SQLite assigns 1 of 5 **type affinities** to each column:

> TEXT, NUMERIC, INTEGER, REAL, BLOB

and you should use any of these affinities when you define the *data type* of a column.

For your case the type affinity determined for a column defined as `String`, according to these rules:

1. If the declared type contains the string "INT" then it is assigned INTEGER affinity.
2. If the declared type of the column contains any of the strings "CHAR", "CLOB", or "TEXT" then that column has TEXT affinity. Notice that the type VARCHAR contains the string "CHAR" and is thus assigned TEXT affinity.
3. If the declared type for a column contains the string "BLOB" or if no type is specified then the column has affinity BLOB.
4. If the declared type for a column contains any of the strings "REAL", "FLOA", or "DOUB" then the column has REAL affinity.
5. Otherwise, the affinity is NUMERIC.

will be `NUMERIC` because none of the first 4 rules can be applied.
So change it to `TEXT` which is the suitable affinity.

You can find all about *data types* in SQLite here: [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Comment: Thank you!! Cleared my doubt